# How to get first paragraph that contains image

Tags: php

Getting first paragraph is easy:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$firstParagraph = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
```

But I need to get first paragraph with image and get src attribute value of img tag. How to do this?

Comment: anything wrong with using js/jquery? Or is that not an option? :)

Comment: An XPath might be more appropriate.

Comment: I have given the answer in jQuery. If you want you can use the same logic via javascript dom element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below some examples using [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Get all `img` elements contained in `p` tags, iterate over them and print the `src` attribute.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));
$query = $xpath->query("//p//img");

foreach($query as $img){
    print $img->getAttribute('src') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Query directly the `src` attributes

```
$query = $xpath->query("//p//img@src");

foreach($query as $domAttribute){
    print $domAttribute->value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

we  output the `src` like this because this will return `DomAttr` objects.

Get directly the first one that matches

```
$result = $xpath->evaluate("string(//p//img/@src)");
print $result . PHP_EOL;
```